# Splitting String pattern with Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Using Regex I have to split String Patterns and expand them.

For Example:

```
String Pattern = "rue Richard2" -----> in 2 string 
Substring1 = "rue Richard" , Substring2 = "2"
```

But for more sophisticated String Pattern like "rue-Richard 2-5", I must split and Expand:

```
Substring1 = "rue-Richard " , Substring2 = "2"
Substring1 = "rue-Richard " , Substring2 = "3"
Substring1 = "rue-Richard " , Substring2 = "4"
Substring1 = "rue-Richard " , Substring2 = "5"
```

But for another more sophisticated String Pattern like "rue-Richard 2,5,7,11", I must split and Expand:

```
Substring1 = "rue-Richard." , Substring2 = "2"
Substring1 = "rue-Richard." , Substring2 = "5"
Substring1 = "rue-Richard." , Substring2 = "7"
Substring1 = "rue-Richard." , Substring2 = "11"
```

Comment: Regex does not look like the correct tool for that. Can you use external libraries?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: One thing is sure: this problem cann't be solved just with a regex pattern. May be you can use regex to split up you string (according to a well defined specification what you need), but then you will need some code to expand you street/housnumber pairs.

Comment: Can't you split the String by space and then split the second element of the split array by comma !

Answer (score 0):

Regexes here won't help, since you have two tasks to do:

- separate non-digits from digits;
- analyze the digits.

An easy solution for this is to use [Guava's `CharMatcher`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
// DIGIT matches all unicode digits, we don't want that
private static final CharMatcher DIGITS = CharMatcher.DIGIT
    .and(CharMatcher.ASCII);

// find first digit index
final int index = DIGITS.indexIn(input);
input.substring(0, index); // part without the digits
input.substring(index); // part with digits
```

Then you "only" have to analyze the digit part.